What do you call a page or list where one mentions all their preferences?
The list includes items like

What I love in a person
People I adore
One thing I am afraid of
My strength
etc

These used to be published in magazines where celebrities would mention all their different likes and dislikes.

In general, it's the full Oxford English Dictionary definition II.10.c profile 1922– A record or report of a person's psychological or behavioural traits, personal preferences, etc., typically based on the analysis of his or her responses in a questionnaire or test. But I expect people who work in celebrity gossip publications have domain-specific terms.

I don't think this type of magazine article has a particular name. It's not common or clearly defined.  The examples "My Strength" and "One thing I am afraid of" don't fit your description, so I'm not certain what you mean. But you could say "A magazine article in which a celebrity describes their preferences".

My favorite things.

As @jamesk says in his comment, there's no generally recognized name for such a list. Just give a description: "my preferences", "what I'm looking for in a plumber", whatever.

You can call the page -
1.Personal Preference Page. (in a diary )
2.Personal Data page.  (In a diary ).
3.A Random List of Loves, Likes and Dislikes (a magazine)

A random list of
Loves, Likes and Dislikes.


Ref. https://happymesshappiness.wordpress.com/2018/02/06/a-random-list-of-loves-likes-and-dislikes/

No magazine would use those.
